# получение данных из нескольких таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

```
    SELECT questions.Name, COUNT(views.qid) AS views, 
        COUNT(comments.qid) AS comments FROM questions

    LEFT JOIN views ON questions.qid = views.qid
    LEFT JOIN comments ON questions.qid = comments.qid

    GROUP BY questions.Name
```

пытаюсь получить данные вида:

```
array(
   [Name] => question_name,
   [views] => КОЛИЧЕСТВО_ПРОСМОТРОВ
   [comments] => КОЛИЧЕСТВО_КОММЕНТАРИЕВ
)
```

где `views` нужно получить количество строк, поэтому я использовал `COUNT()`

но 2 `COUNT'а` отказываются работать, выдают одинаковый результат... подскажите как нужно правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
    SELECT questions.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT views.qid) AS views, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT comments.qid) AS comments FROM questions

    LEFT JOIN views ON questions.qid = views.qid
    LEFT JOIN comments ON questions.qid = comments.qid

    GROUP BY questions.Name
```